# body=body.encode('ascii','ignore')AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, character-encoding, beautifulsoup

Why does the following code give me an error message: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'`?

```
import urllib2                  
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

opener = urllib2.build_opener()         
opener.addheaders = [('user-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

url = ('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink_Floyd')

thisurl= opener.open(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(thisurl)      
title = soup.title.text

body = soup.findAll('p')       
body = body.encode('ascii','ignore')

for i in body:         
    print i.text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to `encode` a list (the result of `findAll` is the list of occurences).  What you need to do is iterate through the list, get the text that you want and encode this.

```
body = soup.findAll('p')

for i in body:
    print i.text.encode('ascii','ignore')
```